# Special characters in less log file make it useless

Tags: less

I want to save the output of the Python help command to a file. Since it uses less, the obvious way is to "s file" while in less. It works, but the words which less shows in bold are screwed up. Any suggestions?

Tons of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `less -R` (or `less -r`).

- the `-r` option will just make the escape codes visible (without interpreting them),
- the `-R` option tries to filter them, cf. `man` page:

> Like  -r,  but  only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form. Unlike -r, the screen appearance is  maintained  correctly  in  most  cases.